# Grouping over the subquery in SQL on unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a query which gets results from temp table. It has aggregate columns which are derived from the temp table:

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT
 SUM(a),
 SUM(b),
 c,
 d,
 id1
FROM
 #tmpTable
 .
 .
 .
 join with many other tables
```

I want to now get the SUM of columns c & d returned from the query along with all other columns. It will be group by id1. It should look something like:

```
+--------------------------------------------
||Sum(A)  |Sum(B)|C     |D        |id1      |
|-------------------------------------------+
|  12     |34    |1     | 3       | 1       |
|-------------------------------------------+
|  22     |37    | 2    | 4       | 2       |
|-------------------------------------------+
|  33     | 55   | 3    | 5       | 1       |
|-------------------------------------------+
| 44      | 25   | 5    | 6       | 2       |
+---------+------+------+---------+---------+
```

Final result should be this:

```
+--------------------------------------------
||Sum(A)  |Sum(B)|Sum(C)|Sum(d)   |id1      |
|-------------------------------------------+
|  12     |34    |4     | 8       | 1       |
|-------------------------------------------+
|  22     |37    | 7    | 10      | 2       |
|-------------------------------------------+
|  33     | 55   | 4    | 8       | 1       |
|-------------------------------------------+
|  44     | 25   | 7    | 10      | 2       |
+---------+------+------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: What grouping do you use to get `sum(a)` and `sum(b)`?

Comment: So sum(A), sum(B) is group by id1,C,D? and sum(C),sum(D) is group by id1?

Comment: Sum(A) and Sum(B) isn’t over id1. There are other id columns which is used for them. For C and D I’ve to use id1. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current real query is summing up `a` and  `b` the way you want and generating that first sample output, maybe something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 SUM(a),
 SUM(b),
 SUM(c) OVER (PARTITION BY id1),
 SUM(d) OVER (PARTITION BY id1),
 id1
FROM
 #tmpTable
 .
 .
 .
 join with many other tables
```

to get the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you have different grouping criteria for A and B, you can group them separately to C and D. The below (using common table expression) might start you on the right track:

```sql
    ; with SummaryValues AS
    (
        select id1, sum(C) as SumC, SUM(D) as SumD
        from #SourceTable
        group by id1
    )
    select SUM(st.A), SUM(st.b), sv.SumC, sv.SumD, st.id1
    from #SourceTable st
    inner join SummaryValues sv
        on st.id1 = sv.id1
    group by <whatever grouping you are using>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    x.sum_a,
    x.sum_b,
    x.sum_c,
    x.sum_d,
    t.id1
from
    tmpTable t
join
(
select
    id1,
    sum(A) as sum_a,
    sum(B) as sum_b,
    sum(C) as sum_c,
    sum(D) as sum_d
from
    tmpTable
group by
    id1
) x on t.id1 = x.id1
```